# $wpdb->insert_id is not working

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get the last inserted in id MySQL but it doesn't return anything. Row is getting inserted in the database and also $wpdb->last_query gives the last inserted query also.
Here is my code

```
  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "request_from";
  $wpdb->insert($table_name, 
      array('pre' => $prefix, 
          'first_name' => $first_name,  
          'middle_name' => $middle_initial, 
          'last_name' => $last_name, 
          'badge_name' => $name_badge, 
          'title' => $title, 
          'company' => $company, 
          'direct_mail' => $direct_mail, 
          'twitter' => $twitter_handle, 
          'direct_phone' => $direct_phone, 
          'address' => $address, 
          'address2' => $address_2,  
          'city' => $city, 
          'state' => $state, 
          'province' => $province, 
          'zip' => $zip_code, 
          'country' => $country, 
          'cc' => $cc, 
          'cc_contact' => $second_contact,  
          'cc_mail' => $second_email, 
          'cc_phone' => $second_phone)
        ); 
$x= $wpdb->last_query;
$id = $wpdb->insert_id
```

I have a column called id with auto increment value

```
id  int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: Seems ; missing $id = $wpdb->insert_id; . Please correct and check

Comment: What exactly is the value of $id after `$id = $wpdb->insert_id`, and how are you checking it? (What does `var_dump($id)` show?)

Comment: Try to dump error with `$wpdb->last_error;` it will show you the problem

Answer (score 1):

Follow wpdb reference in Codex for troubleshooting:

- enable database error display via $wpdb->show_errors()
- check what query is being formed and run via $wpdb->last_query

Please check code by print or dump variable,

```
   global $wpdb;
      $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "request_from";
      $wpdb->insert($table_name, 
          array('pre' => $prefix, 
              'first_name' => $first_name,  
              'middle_name' => $middle_initial, 
              'last_name' => $last_name, 
              'badge_name' => $name_badge, 
              'title' => $title, 
              'company' => $company, 
              'direct_mail' => $direct_mail, 
              'twitter' => $twitter_handle, 
              'direct_phone' => $direct_phone, 
              'address' => $address, 
              'address2' => $address_2,  
              'city' => $city, 
              'state' => $state, 
              'province' => $province, 
              'zip' => $zip_code, 
              'country' => $country, 
              'cc' => $cc, 
              'cc_contact' => $second_contact,  
              'cc_mail' => $second_email, 
              'cc_phone' => $second_phone)
            ); 
    $x= $wpdb->last_query;
    $id = $wpdb->insert_id;
// Let's output the last autogenerated ID.
  echo $wpdb->insert_id;

  // This returns the same result
  echo mysql_insert_id();
```